# Read linux console PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

I want to read the console logs of a process that is running, I currently have this

```
$output = shell_exec('pgrep tfs');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

And that returns me a random number like 34034

I've almost never worked with linux before so I dont really know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that that's what [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) does, right? It returns the process ID of the process you're asking about. So that's not a random number you're getting back. Your script is working perfectly.

Why don't you find the actual log file itself (usually in `/var/logs`) and use something like [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to open and parse it?